# Как вводить другие клавиши?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Как вводить другие клавиши? Способом нижу можно вводить значения клавиш, а как ввести например ctrl, alt или f5.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    setlocale(0, "");
    int a;

    do
    {
        a = _getche();
        cout << a;
    if (a == 'w')
    {
        cout << "Вперёд\n";
    }
    if (a == 'a')
    {
        cout << "Влево\n";
    }
    if (a == 's')
    {
        cout << "Назад\n";
    }
    if (a == 'd')
    {
        cout << "Вправо\n";
    }
} while (true);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Непосредственно сам C/C++ ничего о клавиатуре не знает - для него есть только поток ввода. Поэтому такая тонкая работа с клавиатурой должна выполняться средствами операционной системы. Как я понимаю, вас интересует Windows, консольное приложение. Тут может помочь, например, функция Win32 API [GetKeyState](http://www.cyberguru.ru/programming/win32/win32-keyboard-functions-page12.html) или, скажем, [GetKeyboardState](http://www.cyberguru.ru/programming/win32/win32-keyboard-functions-page10.html). Только при этом логика программы должна быть иной - вы должны сами опрашивать состояние клавиатуры и реагировать на нажатие/отпускание клавиш.

Вот, посмотрите, например:

```
for(;;)
{
    char a = _getche();
    cout << a << "   " << GetKeyState(VK_CONTROL)
         << "   " << GetKeyState(VK_MENU) << endl;
}
```

P.S. немного соврал: в принципе, та же `_getche()` дает дополнительную информацию для расширенных клавиш. Если вы и не отличите, скажем, `f` и `Alt-f`, то стрелку вправо от Alt-стрелки вправо - запросто, надо только выполнять 2 чтения `getche()`. Так и для функциональных клавиш будет два возврата - нулевой и с кодом клавиши (`0x3F` для `F5`, о которой вы спрашивали :))

Comment: #include "windows.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
 for (;;)
 {
  if (GetKeyState(VK_LSHIFT) == 1)
   cout << "NumLock ON" << endl;
  else
   cout << "NumLock OFF" << endl;
 }
 return 0;
}\\Спасибо, я понял!!!

Comment: Пожалуйста приведите маленький пример.А то я не понимаю слегка, насчёт -  выполнить 2 чтения getche().

Comment: @ПилюгаАлександр Попробуйте выполнить такой код - `    for(;;)
    {
        int a = _getche();
        printf("\n%c %08X  %08X  %08X\n",a,a,GetKeyState(VK_CONTROL),GetKeyState(VK_MENU));
    }` - и понажимать разные клавиши. Вы увидите, что при нажатии той же `F5` выведется *две* строки, а не одна, т.е. будет выполнено *два* чтения функцией `_getche()` на одну клавишу.

Comment: Да, getch почти всё считывает кроме с левой стороны Tab и ниже , а справой shift и ниже кроме пробела.